# Getting the text of an element on one page and displaying it on another page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 pages, call them page1.html and page2.html.  page2.html has a paragraph with an id of 'number' that contains only a single number which will update based on other things on the page. `<p id="number">5</p>`

So on page2.html, `console.log(document.querySelector('#number').innerHTML);` will return '5'.

I want to use JavaScript (or jQuery) to get this number from page2.html and display it on page1.html.  I am trying to use jQuery's get method, but it's not working yet. I can't use localStorage because page2.html isn't a page the user will access first.

On page1.html, I have tried these pieces of code:

```
$.get('page2.html', function(text){
    var numberToDisplay = $('#number').text();
    alert(numberToDisplay);
});
```

I've also tried this:

```
$.get('page2.html', function(text){
    var numberToDisplay = $(text).find('#number');
    alert(numberToDisplay);
});
```

Is there something I can fix in my code, or is there something else entirely I should do?

Comment: You could use the  browsers local storage.